# How to autofill column with specific value (number) until the row of another column in excel using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need column J to be filled with the value 1 in all cells until the rows that are filled in column A. Could someone provide me with the vba code for the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to autofill 2010 until the row of column B with value 1:

```
Sub test()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value = 2010

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) How can I use this method to fill worksheets 2-5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below codes-

```
Sub FillCells()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim rng As Range

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lr
        Cells(i, "J") = 1
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) How can I use this method to fill only worksheets 2-5 with a button thats on worksheet 1?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the  next code line:

```
     Range("J2:J" & Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value = 1
```

**Edited**

You asked in a comment to another answer something about doing it for specific sheets.

Please, try the next way:

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
  
  For i = 2 To 5
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    ws.Range("J2:J" & ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value = 1
  Next i
```